# Sectigo certificate is accepted by Google Chrome on my Android CK65 Honeywell device even though Sectigo is not on the list of Trusted credentials

Tags: android, google-chrome, ssl-certificate

I want to make sure I understand which Certificate Authorities are really trusted by Google Chrome so I can implement similar logic in my custom browser using WebView. I followed these steps:

1. Open Settings.
2. Tap “Security & location”
3. Tap “Encryption & credentials”
4. Tap “Trusted credentials.” This will display a list of all trusted certs on the device.

The list is Alphabetical and Sectigo RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA is not there. However when I start Google Chrome and navigate to https://sectigo.com/ the browser shows that their certificate is OK. Any idea why?